# How send $_FILES via curl

Tags: php, file, curl

I try send `$_FILES` via `curl`:

```
$post = array('files' => $_FILES);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://test.com/upload_page');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But i get notice for row `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);`:

> Notice:  Array to string conversion

I know that `$post` should been as string, but how it make for `$_FILES` ?

Comment: It means you can only send one file at a time maybe you should run a foreach loop if you want to send all the files in $_FILES

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for upload image with curl using php

```
$file_name_with_full_path = realpath('./sample.jpeg');

$post = array('extra_info' => '123456','file_contents'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```